# Arriving at $P_{n+1}'(x) + P_{n-1}'(x) = 2xP_n'(x) + P_n(x)$ from Lagrange's $g(x,t) = (1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, physics

Consider the following generating function for the Lagrange polinomials:

$$g(x,t) = (1-2xt+t^2)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n$$

If we differentiate:

$$\frac{\partial g(t,x)}{\partial x} = \frac{t}{(1-2xt-t^2)^{3/2}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n'(x)t^n$$

which leads to:

$$(1-2xt+t^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n'(x)t^n-t\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^n = 0\tag{1}$$

**The coefficient of each power of $t$ is set to equal to $0$ and we obtain:**

$$P_{n+1}'(x) + P_{n-1}'(x) = 2xP_n'(x) + P_n(x)$$

However, I'm having trouble equating these coefficients to $0$. We get from (1):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n'(x)t^n+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}-2xP_n'(x)t^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n'(x)t^{n+2} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}P_n(x)t^{n+1} = 0$$

Now what exactly it means to make the coefficients to be equal to $0$? I should take the coefficients from the left side that have no $t$ in them and equate to $0$? But there are series which always have $t$. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You try to figure out the coefficient of $t^{n} $ on LHS and equate it to $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh but there's $t^{n+1}$ and $t^{n+2}$ involved

Comment: From the first $\sum$ you get the desired coefficient as $P'_{n} (x) $ and from second $\sum$ you get $-2xP'_{n-1}(x)$. Try for other terms in same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Guerlando . If you open the summation, you can see that for coefficient of $t^{2}$ we have $$ \left( P_{2}'(x) -2xP_{1}'(x) +P_{0}'(x) -P_{1}(x) \right) t^{2} $$ and setting it to 0 will get the desired $$ P_{2}'(x) +P_{0}'(x) = 2xP_{1}'(x)  +P_{1}(x)$$ this will happen for $t^{m}, \: m \ge 2$. For $m<2$, you can think of the polynomials $P_{n}(x)$ with negative $n$ are equal to zero, since at the beginning you dont have those polynomials.

The coefficients is set to 0 so that we can have a relation of the polynomials that satisfy the original equation : 
$$(1-2xt+t^{2})^{-1/2} = \sum P_{n}(x)t^{n} $$
Regards, Arief.